# C - What is wrong with this code?

Tags: c

I made a program which takes a user to input number, if user inputed number less than 0 or greater than 100, then program returns to main function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a; scanf("%d", &a);
    if(a > 100 || a < 0) {
        printf("Going back to program.");
        return main();
    } else {
        printf("Your number: %d\n", a);
    }
}
```

**But this code doesn't take a input and it just prints "Your number: 0".**
**So, what is wrong with this code?**

Comment: Cannot replicate when entering `42`. What did you enter?

Comment: Why you want to call `main()`? You can loop back to scanning...

Comment: it´s working for me. I would add a output before "input: " before entering something and use a loop-back instead method call but calus 0-100 and others are working.

Comment: `surendra:~/surendra$ ./a.out
-1
Going back to program.-5
Going back to program.-100
Going back to program.101
Going back to program.111
Going back to program.222
Going back to program.57
Your number: 57`

This is the output upon executing the same code bro!! On the other hand, instead of calling main function and creating unnecessary stacks, you can simply use do-while loop.

Comment: @filip204What is your OS ?

Comment: Are you using a C++ compiler to compile this? (calling `main()` from itself is allowed in C, but is UB in C++).

Comment: No, i'm using Tutorialspoint online IDE to compile C program.

Comment: Hum. If you unroll the recursion by adopting one of the answers below, what happens then?

Comment: @filip204 for learning you should get an IDE on _your_ computer. Online IDEs are just fine for small demonstrations but they are terrible for any real usage.

Comment: Tutorialspoint is known to be a bad source overall for learning programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using recursion here (calling `main` again from `main`) is overly complicated and useless.

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a;

  do
  {
    scanf("%d", &a);
  } while (a > 100 || a < 0);   // simply repeat scan if a is out of bounds

  printf("Your number: %d\n", a);
}
```

This is basic C knowledge. You probbaly should start reading your C textbook.

Comment: You probably also want to check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: @moooeeeep let's keep it simple for the moment, `scanf` is evil anyway ;-)

Comment: @MichaelWalz yeah but this is basic knowledge in every tutorial... By the way aren't you missing a return in your main?

Comment: @TobiasMöller no need for `return` here, `main` implicitly returns 0, if there is non `return` statement. Don't rembember which chapter of which standard though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not good... A better way of doing it would be to use a loop

**Better Solution**

```
int main(){
    int a;
    do {
        scanf("%d", &a);
    } while(a > 100 || a < 0);
    printf("Your number: %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

**Your working solution**

```
int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if(a > 100 || a < 0) {
        printf("Recursion");//You are not going back you go further in depth (Recursion)
        return main();
    } else {
        printf("Your number: %d\n", a);
        return 0;//You need to return in if and in else
    }
}
```

This is basic knowledge about programming (with c). I think you are a beginner so maybe you want to start with an Tutorial?

Comment: If user enters non-number, your code has undefined behavior (using uninitialized variable). Never nice in a SO answer.

Comment: @hyde whats your problem? Its just a simple example of course you should do other things if you can... I wouldn't use scanf at all for user input

Comment: I just think that examples which show bad programming habits are bad examples. Checking return value of `scanf` and exiting if it's invalid would be just 1 line of extra code, so there's really no excuse in leaving it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, it should work.

`scanf()` reads from `stdin`. Depending on how and where your program runs `stdin` can have different meanings.

On tutorialspoint.com, you have to supply data to `stdin` before running your program by using the "Stdin" tab.[image: screen]